# Getting RGB colors of selected area in an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcrop

I have prepared a code that can give the average color of an image properly. But now I want users to select some area in that image and get average RGB values of that specific area.

For this purpose, I tried using the jCrop library and it also gave me the image x, y, width, and height values after selection. But when I apply these jCrop variables inside the `getRGB` function the function stops working.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Jcrop Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-jcrop/0.9.15/css/jquery.Jcrop.css">
</head>

<body>
  <img id="img" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAABkCAIAAAD/gAIDAAABD0lEQVR4nOzSMQ0CYRgEUUJOAQUmMIEQapycA4IZbCEAA38z1ccl7ynYTHbb9+/p/zxe9+kJC+fpAUciViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFaw3a7v6Q0Ll+dnesKCZwViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgW/AAAA//+j+wYF8oSWtwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="
  />
  <div>
    <p class='inr'></p>
    <p class='ing'></p>
    <p class='inb'></p>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-jcrop/0.9.15/js/jquery.Jcrop.js"></script>
  <script>
    $('#img').on('load change', function() {
      var rgb = getRGB(this);
      $('.inr').text(rgb.r);
      $('.ing').text(rgb.g);
      $('.inb').text(rgb.b);
    });

    function getRGB(img) {
      var dx, dy, dw, dh;
      $("#img").Jcrop({
        onSelect: function(c) {
          var dx = c.x,
            dy = c.y,
            dw = c.w,
            dh = c.h;
          console.log(dx, dy, dw, dh);
        }
      })
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
        context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        rgb = {
          r: 0,
          g: 0,
          b: 0
        },
        i = -4,
        count = 0,
        height = canvas.height = img.naturalHeight,
        width = canvas.width = img.naturalWidth;
      context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      var data = context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height),
        length = data.data.length;
      while ((i += 4) < length) {
        ++count;
        rgb.r += data.data[i];
        rgb.g += data.data[i + 1];
        rgb.b += data.data[i + 2];
      }
      rgb.r = (rgb.r / count);
      rgb.g = (rgb.g / count);
      rgb.b = (rgb.b / count);
      return rgb;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example how to get the color of the clicked point.

1. Event handler was changed to `click` (to actually process click event with its XY coordinates)
2. Position can be managed by shifting an image width `Y` times and then shifting by `X` pixels from the left side.

You can try it and then extend processed point to selected area.

```js
$('#img').on('click', function(e) {
    var rgb = getRGB(this);
    $('.inr').text(rgb.r);
    $('.ing').text(rgb.g);
    $('.inb').text(rgb.b);
});

function getRGB(img) {
    var dx, dy, dw, dh;
    $("#img").Jcrop({
        onSelect: function(c) {
            var dx = c.x,
                dy = c.y,
                dw = c.w,
                dh = c.h;
            console.log(dx, dy, dw, dh);
        }
    })
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
        context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        rgb = {
            r: 0,
            g: 0,
            b: 0
        },
        height = canvas.height = img.naturalHeight,
        width = canvas.width = img.naturalWidth;
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    var data = context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height),
        length = data.data.length;
    var position = (width * event.offsetY + event.offsetX) * 4;
    rgb.r = data.data[position];
    rgb.g = data.data[++position];
    rgb.b = data.data[++position];
    return rgb;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Jcrop Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-jcrop/0.9.15/css/jquery.Jcrop.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-jcrop/0.9.15/js/jquery.Jcrop.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img id="img" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAABkCAIAAAD/gAIDAAABD0lEQVR4nOzSMQ0CYRgEUUJOAQUmMIEQapycA4IZbCEAA38z1ccl7ynYTHbb9+/p/zxe9+kJC+fpAUciViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFaw3a7v6Q0Ll+dnesKCZwViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgViBWIFYgW/AAAA//+j+wYF8oSWtwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="/>
    <div>
      <p class='inr'></p>
      <p class='ing'></p>
      <p class='inb'></p>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```